# Recalculate ten cells every ten seconds

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use Google Maps API for around 2,000 locations. I was told the API only allows ten calculations every ten seconds hence we need the Excel sheet to do that. My code:

```
'recalculate cells
Sub Recalculatecells()
Dim irow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer


'    Worksheets("Sheet2").Active
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        iRow = ActiveCell.Row

        Range("N1").Value = irow

        For i = 1 To iRow
            Range("N" & Str(i)).Formula = "=GetCoordinates(A" & i & ")"
        j = j + 1
        If j = 10 Then

            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
            j = 0
        Else
            j = j + 1
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

This is currently giving an error on the line:

```
Range("N" & Str(i)).Formula= "=GetCoordinates(A" & i & ")"
```

(Note: `=getcoordinates` is the function to run the Maps API.)

I don't know why the error is there, once this error is removed would the code work?

Comment: not sure, but maybe =GetCoordinates(" & range("a" & I).value & ")"

Comment: The key of the problem is to know if the error occurs at the first call to `GetCoordinates`or at the 11th call?

Comment: Thanks for the responses.. user5414798, unfortunately your suggestion did not fix the error. @A.S.H. The error occurs at the 1st call of `GetCoordinates`.

Comment: Can you please post the prototype of `GetCoordinates` and the value in the cell `A1`?

Comment: In case some were wondering, the GetCoordinates is a Function, this is the start of the code for it:

    `Option Explicit

     Function GetCoordinates(Address As String) As String`

Answer (score 1):

The [Application.OnTime method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165.aspx) can call the routine that it is in.

```
Sub Recalculatecells()
    Application.StatusBar = "Calculating ..."
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("N1:N10").Calculate
    Application.StatusBar = vbNullString
    'put something here to optionally exit the timed loop
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10), "Recalculatecells"
End Sub
```

I find this allows more freedom for working on the workbook instead of staying within the same sub procedure and mucking with a `For ... Next` increment counter.

Comment: Problem is, as I understood, the error occurs at the first time when `GetCoordinates` is used.

Comment: We dont know much about that function and the content of `A1`. We need your `Crystal Ball` so badly now!!! :P :D

Comment: If the `GetCoordinates` is already a working function in 10 cells on the worksheet (albeit in a non-volatile mode), a recalculation can be forced on those individual cells. Without going into the API completely, I was offering a better recursive loop than resetting the increment counter in a For.. Next loop.

Comment: I agree totally with your improvements, since I wasn't comfortable with the timing method in the OP. And yes, it might be that the API function was called elsewhere in the worksheet. (proves that we do need that Crystal Ball ;) )

Comment: No worries. Comments always welcomed and appreciated (although I can be admittedly terse in my responses). :)